# How do I sort jumbled words from the dictionary using Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I cannot get my program to compile.  What I am trying to do is get the program to print out all the jumbled words with the dictionary words that can be made from it printed next to it.  I believe it is an error in the way I nested my loops but I can't figure it out.  Is anyone able to give me a hand?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
     {
     if (args.length < 2) die("Must give name of two input files on cmd line.");

    BufferedReader dictionaryFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[0] ));
    BufferedReader jumbleFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(args[0] ));

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> jumbleWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> dictionaryWords = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<String> keysList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(jumbleFile.ready())
    {
        String jWord=jumbleFile.readLine();
        jumbleWords.add(jWord);
    }
    jumbleFile.close();

    Collections.sort(jumbleWords);

    while(dictionaryFile.ready())
    {
        String dWord= dictionaryFile.readLine();
        String dictWord= toCanonical(dWord);
        if(map.containsKey(dictWord))
        {
            map.get(dictWord);
            map.put(dWord, map.get(dictWord));
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<String> dictionaryWords2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            dictionaryWords2.add(dWord);
            map.put(dictWord, dictionaryWords2);

    }
        for( String i : map.keySet())
        {
            keysList.add(i);    
        }
        Collections.sort(keysList);

        for (String key :  keysList)
        {
            System.out.print(key);
            String toCanJWord= toCanonical(key);
            if(map.containsKey(toCanJWord))
            {
                map.get(toCanJWord);
                Collections.sort(map.get(toCanJWord));
                for(map.get(toCanJWord))
                {
                        System.out.print(toCanJWord);
                }
          }

            System.out.println();
}




private static String toCanonical( String word )
{
    char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(letters);
    return new String(letters);    
}
 private static void die( String errmsg )
    {
                System.out.println( "\nFATAL ERROR: " + errmsg + "\n" );
                System.exit(0);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Your code contains a mighty host of bugs, but one which causes an almost immediate halt to further processing is `for(map.get(toCanJWord))`. Once you resolve that, I suggest you stop and reconsider your approach. `String` is immutable - using `Arrays.sort(char[])` on its' backing array (like in `toCanonical`) can cause you all sorts of grief.

Comment: It now compiles, but it is just an infinite output of letters

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues. First you are missing a `}` at the end of the `for loop` here:

```
for (String key :  keysList)
        {
            System.out.print(key);
            String toCanJWord = toCanonical(key);
            if(map.containsKey(toCanJWord))
            {
                map.get(toCanJWord);
                Collections.sort(map.get(toCanJWord));
                //this isn't correct. Not sure what you are trying to do here
                //but this is why it won't compile
                for(map.get(toCanJWord))
                {
                        System.out.print(toCanJWord);
                }
          }

    }//missing this closing bracket
```

There is also an issue with your for loop, see the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is wrong:

```
for(map.get(toCanJWord))
{
   System.out.print(toCanJWord);
}
```

It needs to be of the format:

```
for(String wordToPrint : map.get(toCanJWord))
{
   System.out.print(wordToPrint );
}
```

Comment: How do I sort the array that toCanJWord is in if I don't know which array it is in?     'Collections.sort(map.get(toCanJWord))'     won't work?

Comment: Assuming that you want the map to contain: <canonicalWord,List<dictWords>, this part of your code needs to change:<br/>     _italic_ if(map.containsKey(dictWord))
         {
             map.get(dictWord);
             map.put(dWord, map.get(dictWord));
         }   <br/> , you need to get a list of the words for the key(canonical word), and add the new dictionary word to it